# HelloWorld with JavaFXPorts and gradle on Android

Tags: javafx, gluon, javafxports, gluon-mobile

so I'll try to build a mobile application with Gluon and JavaFX.

So, i follow this step.

1. Install ADT and add ANDROID_HOME to my enviroment (OS Mac)
2. Install SceneBuilder from official site
3. Install last eclipse version (neon)
4. generate a FXML file from ScendeBuilder
5. With eclipse wizard, i generate a SingleViewGluon project
6. import FXML on my eclipse project and use in my JavaFX application

Now I try to generate apk from console, I'm in the root of project and launch

```
./gradlew clean build
```

and that's ok, after

```
./gradlew android
```

and i get that's error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'mergeClassesIntoJar' during up-to-date check.
>     java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/franksisca/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs/android-support-multidex.jar
>     (No such file or directory)
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

How i solve this? Someone has a step-by-step tutorial to build a mobile application with JavaFXPorts?

thanks in advance

Comment: I solved the issue. The problem is in an oldest library inside the SDK manager. Need to install EXTRAS Resources from SDK Manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems android-support-multidex.jar which is necessary for the **task 'mergeClassesIntoJar'** is not Found. So Go to Sdk Manager.exe, which is located in the root of **ANDROID_HOME**, and update all the repositories. And run the gradle clean build.

This should probably Work.